# Context.RewritePath changes Request.Url.AbsolutePath value. Can it be different?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting

I'm using asp.net MVC 3 and when I rewrite an url I need to get the previous url values. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

User Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery.ToString() to get the previous URL

Comment: Not true - the rewrite is within the same request context as it's server side.